# RadDatePicker SelectedDateChanged issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have RadDatePicker control with SelectedDateChanged event. When I change the Date the event fires with Confirm window. When I click on 'Cancel' button RadDatePicker1_SelectedDateChanged invokes again and it displays Confirm window twice. When I click on 'OK' button it works fine. What could be the problem? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
  <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedDateChanged="RadDatePicker1_SelectedDateChanged" >
                         </telerik:RadDatePicker>


protected void RadDatePicker1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string radalertscript = "<script language='javascript'>function f(){ radconfirm('Are you sure?', confirmChange, 400, 100) ; Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}; Sys.Application.add_load(f);</script>";
                     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "radalert33", radalertscript);
 }
```

Here is Javascript function

```
function confirmChange(args) {
    if (args) {
        __doPostBack("<%= hiddenButton1.UniqueID %>", "");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an unnessary postback if you're just using it to render some javascript.

Could you do your confirm dialog on the client side?

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-on-date-selecting.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmChange(sender, eventArgs) {
    var date = eventArgs.get_renderDay().get_date();
    var dfi = sender.DateTimeFormatInfo;
    var formattedDate = dfi.FormatDate(date, dfi.ShortDatePattern);
    eventArgs.set_cancel(!confirm("Are you sure you want to " +
    (eventArgs.get_isSelecting() ? "select " : "unselect ") +
    formattedDate + "?"));
}
</script>

<telerik:RadCalendar ID="RadCalendar1" runat="server">
    <ClientEvents OnDateSelecting="ConfirmChange" />
</telerik:RadCalendar>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this suggestion. Is there anyway I can cancel the Date Selection when RadConfirm 'cancel' clicked?

Comment: I didn't put together a demo page but that there should do it. If you have some problems post up a comment and I'll drop the code in a page and try to help

Comment: I am still having issue with Cancel button with RadConfirm. It looks like DatePicker control already changed the Date when selected the new date. I am not sure if I can go back to the old value after 'Cancel' clicked.

Comment: Using the OnDateSelecting is kind of chatty, the code I have up there will generate 4 alert boxes. Two for de-selecting and re-selecting the initial date and two more for delecting the old date and selecting the new one. It may be better to do an alert against the OnDateSelected. It gives you access to the old date and new date so if they hit cancel you could just reset back to the original. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-on-date-selected.html